# Is there a $q$-analogue to Shapiro's convolution identity?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, combinatorial-identities, q-analogs

Let $C_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n$ denote the Catalan numbers.

This question is motivated by the (unanswered) [MO post by Alexander Burstein](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391533/a-bijective-proof-for-the-odd-companion-to-shapiros-catalan-convolution) and [my own (answered by Fedor Petrov) MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393119/looking-for-a-q-analogue-of-a-binomial-identity).
Specifically, Shapiro's convolution formula states that
$$\sum_{k=0}^nC_{2k}C_{2n-2k}=4^nC_n. \tag1$$

> **QUESTION.**  Is there a $q$-analogue to this "elegant" identity in equation (1)?

Comment: There are several such convolutions involving the factor of $4$. For example, for $f(x)=A025227(x)$, we have $(f(x)-f(-x))^2=(xr)\circ(4x^2)$, where $r(x)$ is the ogf for the large Schröder numbers, and $(A185010(x))^2=m(4x)$, where $m(x)$ is the ogf for the Motzkin numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

George E.Andrews gives a $q$-analog for Shapiro's convolution identity in the article [On Shapiroʼs Catalan convolution](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aam.2010.07.003). The $q$-analog is

$$\sum_{j=0}^n q^{2j} C_{2j+1}(1,-q) C_{2n+1-2j}(1,-q) = \frac{-q^{2n+1}(-q^2 : q^2)_{n-1} C_{n+1}(1,-q)}{(-q:q^2)_{n+1}}$$
where
$$C_n(\lambda,q) = \frac{q^{2n}(\frac{-\lambda}{q}:q^2)_n}{(q^2:q^2)_n}$$
and $\lim_{q\to 1} C_{n+1}(1,-q) = -2^{-2n-1} C_n$.
Taking $q \to 1$ and multiplying by the needed power of $2$ in the above $q$-identity gives Shapiros Catalan convolution.

Comment: Thank you for this info!